# Wrong output by C Program

Tags: c, function, struct

Can any one find the flaw and explain the below program? I will brief you,
1) Using structures in the program to store information about a products.
2) Finding the lowest price and displaying it.
All works fine but output does not give the lowest value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct product{
    int code;
    char name[30];
    float price;
    int qty;
};

void prodata(struct product *p,int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n Enter the Item Code. : ");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].code);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n Enter the Item Name. : ");
        scanf("%s",&p[i].name);
        printf("\n Enter the Item Price. : ");
        scanf("%f",&p[i].price);
        printf("\n Enter the Item Quantity in hand. : ");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].qty);
    }
}
void dispdata(struct product *p, int n){
    int i;
    int min;
    min = 0;  
    for ( i = 1 ; i < n ; i++ ){
        if (p[i].price < p[min].price) {
            min = i;    
        }
    }
    printf("\n ** The Cheapest Product ** \n");
    printf("\n The Product Code        : %d \n",p[min].code);
    printf("\n The Product Name is     : %s \n",p[min].name);
    printf("\n The Product Price is    : %f \n",p[min].price);
    printf("\n The Product Stock       : %d \n",p[min].qty);
}

main(){
    struct product *p=NULL;
    int n;
    printf("\n Product Information. \n");
    printf("\n Please Enter the Number of Items : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n<=1){
        printf("\n Please Enter correct number of items : ");
        scanf("%d",&n); 
    }
    p =(struct product*)malloc(sizeof(struct product)*n);
    prodata(p,n);
    dispdata(p,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0` and `for(i=1`, for one, and `min=i`. you're NOT comparing price to price, you're comparing price to loop index.

Comment: `if (p[i].price < min) {` --> `if (p[i].price < p[min].price) {`

Comment: Thanks Marc. I have done the correction, but still the output is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (p[i].price < min) {
min = i;    
}
```

You're setting the min to be the index, not the actual price of the object.

Comment: Thanks danielku97, done with correction but still no success.

Comment: I would also try the answer by Raymond.Aggarwal, not sure why its downvoted because it makes sense, you will be skipping your first object as its zero index based.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Daniel's response make sure to index i at 0. Your for statements should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {....
```

Right now your missing 1 whole product since your for loop starts counting at 1 and ends after i iterates to (n-1) and executes the code block in the for loop

Comment: Raymond your efforts highly appreciated. However I am trying to min =0 so I am comparing p[i].price with p[min].price, should this give a problem ? The output is the last input and not the lowest. Please help.